# Connectedness of a cartesian product

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. Show that the productspace $X\times Y$ is connected $\Leftrightarrow X,Y$ are connected.

Could someone give me some pointers? I'm **not** looking for a full solution, but for some hints, to help me where I got stuck.

#### Proof:

$\Rightarrow$

Say $X$ is not connected, then there exist $U,V \not = \varnothing$ open, such that $X = U\sqcup V$.

Now consider $U\times Y$ and $V\times Y$. Both of these sets are non-empty.
Since $U, V\in \tau_X$ both sets are open. And since $U\cap V=\varnothing$ $(U\times Y) \cap (V\times Y) = \varnothing$.

Since $X\times Y = (U\times Y) \cup (V\times Y)$ $X\times Y$ would not be connected. Contradiction.

$\Leftarrow$

Say $X\times Y$ is not connected, then there exists $U,V\not = \varnothing$, open in $X\times Y$ such that $X\times Y = U\sqcup V$.

I was thinking of continuing in the way as ($\Rightarrow$), setting $U=U_X\times U_Y$ and $V=V_X\times V_Y$, and then showing something like $U = U_X\sqcup V_X$ which would lead to a contradiction.

**But** I don't think the existance of $U\sqcup V$ means $U$ can be written als $U_X\times U_Y$ can it? (see picture)
[image: connectedness]

Comment: The proof I know for $(\Leftarrow)$ relies on the following $$$$ **Lemma**:
Let $X, Y$ topological spaces. Let $Y$ be connected and let $f:X\to Y$ a surjective and continuous *open* map such that $$\forall y\in Y,\, f^{-1}(y)\text{ is connected}$$ Then, $X$ is connected $$$$
I do not know if there exists one more similar to your approach (which I'd be curious to see, by the way).

Comment: Specifically, you cannot (not immediately, at the very least) assume that $U=U_X\times U_Y$: think of $\mathbb{R}^2$. $\{ \|(x,y)\|>1\}$ cannot be written as such.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli in fact being a quotient map is enough. Here the projection is open and so indeed a quotient map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof of this fact needs a good idea: firstly you should fix some $x \in X$ and write
$$X \times Y = \bigcup_{y \in Y} ((\{ x\} \times Y) \cup (X \times \{ y\}))$$
Secondly, you need to use twice the following proposition:

> If $\{ U_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha}$ is a family of connected subspaces of a space $S$ and $\bigcap_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}$ is not empty, then $\bigcup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}$ is a connected subspace of $S$.

You use it to show that all sets of the form $(\{ x\} \times Y) \cup (X \times \{ y\})$ are connected, and then you use it another time to show that $X \times Y$ is connected.

Comment: That's a ‎nifty way of cutting $X\times Y$ in pieces. Nice!

Comment: Is phi connected in lR?